# TV show that involves teens/kids going to another world

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember from the show that the kids are live actors that are transported into another world where they use CGI for that side, or at least I think it is CGI. It is not *Code Lyoko* or *ReBoot: The Guardian Code*, but it is like those shows. Another thing I remember from the show is a red wheel on a pipe that I think has some importance in going to the other world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking of *[Zixx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zixx) (2004-2009)*.

It involves teens travelling back & forth between the real world (presented in live-action) and a virtual world (presented in CGI), and the portal between worlds is opened by twisting a circular valve on a pipe.